# Throwing exception from CompletableFuture hangs get() and join() in Java 17

Tags: java, asynchronous, freeze, completable-future, java-17

After I have switched from Java 11 to Java 17 (OpenJDK installed from Ubuntu 20.04 repository), the following code doesn't work:

```java
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<String> streamFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            throw MyException.wrapIfNeeded(new Exception("MyException"));
        });
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = streamFuture.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e));
        }
        System.out.println("Result: " + Objects.toString(result));
    }

    static class MyException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3349188601484197015L;

        public MyException(Throwable cause) {
            super(cause == null ? null : cause.getMessage(), cause);
        }

        public static MyException wrapIfNeeded(Throwable e) {
            return e instanceof MyException ? (MyException) e : new MyException(e);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a problem in `streamFuture.get()` - it hangs infinitely. I dug deeper and found that in `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool` there is a method `unmanagedBlock(ManagedBlocker blocker)` which looks like

```java
    /** ManagedBlock for external threads */
    private static void unmanagedBlock(ManagedBlocker blocker)
        throws InterruptedException {
        if (blocker == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        do {} while (!blocker.isReleasable() && !blocker.block());
    }
```

and the program hangs infinitely in the do-while loop.

EDIT:
I found out the problem is cause by the `toString()` method added to my custom exception class. For some reason it started to be a problem after Java 11

Comment: Cannot reproduce with windows and open jdk 17.0.1. Is that all code needed to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @samabcde yes and I run the code in Eclipse 2021-09. More details about my env:
```
$ java --version
openjdk 17 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: @samabcde sorry, I was wrong. Indeed the problem were somewhere else  - in my custom exception class that I simplified in an original post. I edited my post and explained where is the problem. Thanks for your try to help me!

Comment: If you "found" a solution, then dont update the question, but write a self answer ... when you assume this problem is something that other future readers might care about.

Comment: Since your custom exception type does not introduce any properties, I’m wondering why you overrode `toString()` at all. What does the `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this)` deliver which the original inherited `toString()` method does not?

Comment: @Holger my custom exception had more fields. I simplified it here for readability. `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this)` is from Apache Commons Lang and I used overrode `toString()` method for logging purpose

Answer (score 8):

#### The problem is due to `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString` use encapsulated java API.

We can try something like `MyException.wrapIfNeeded(new NullPointerException("")).toString()`
And will see

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field static final long java.lang.RuntimeException.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @b4c966a

#### Why will this cause hang infinitely?

In [`CompletableFuture.AsyncSupply#run`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17+35/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#L1762) method

```java
    static final class AsyncSupply<T> extends ForkJoinTask<Void>
        implements Runnable, AsynchronousCompletionTask {
    ...
        public void run() {
            CompletableFuture<T> d; Supplier<? extends T> f;
            if ((d = dep) != null && (f = fn) != null) {
                dep = null; fn = null;
                if (d.result == null) {
                    try {
                        d.completeValue(f.get());
                    } catch (Throwable ex) {
                        d.completeThrowable(ex);
                    }
                }
                d.postComplete();
            }
        }
```

Since `MyException` is thrown, `d.completeThrowable(ex);` is called, inside this method, it will wrap the exception to `CompletionException`, which will call the constructor of `Throwable` with `MyException` as `cause`.

```java
    public Throwable(Throwable cause) {
        fillInStackTrace();
        detailMessage = (cause==null ? null : cause.toString());
        this.cause = cause;
    }
```

When `cause.toString()` is called, it will throw the exception mentioned in the beginning,
so `d.completeThrowable(ex);` is not executed completely and hence the program will hang forever.

Comment: Great answer for a such a ridiculous problem within the JDK 17

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem is cause by the `toString()` method added to my custom exception class. For some reason it (or to be more precise: `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);`) started to be a problem after Java 11.